# Are there any cons of using this on javascript instead of a context variable?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coding-style, standards, aurelia

I'm working on an Aurelia project with other developers,

some of them are using ***this.*** and some are declaring a context variable

What I was wondering is if there is any performance difference, memory allocation or any standard of use on Javascript for the usage.

---

Example with ***this***:

```
    activate() {
            this.isLoading = true;
            this.modeText = "Edit";
            this.service.getX(this.appState.StoreId,this.variableX).then(response => {
                let stuff = JSON.parse(response.response);
                this.widget = stuff;
                this.isLoading = false;
            });
}
```

---

Example without this:

```
    activate() {    
            var context = this;
            context.isLoading = true;
            context.modeText = "Edit";
            context.service.getX(context.appState.StoreId,context.variableX).then(response => {
                let stuff = JSON.parse(response.response);
                context.widget = stuff;
                context.isLoading = false;
            });
}
```

Comment: Both of these are slightly different though. `context` is always the same, however in the first example, `this` is different inside the `.then` function.
I imagine they define `context` so they don't need to use `apply()` or `call()`

Comment: @MattLishman: That's be true if they were using `function () {}` in the `.then` function, but since they're using arrow functions (which bind `this` to their lexical scope), it'll be the same. So I think with these particular examples, there's no real difference in functionality. Your reasoning is right though, generally when I've seen a `context` variable like that it's been so the right `this` value can be accessed in a callback.

Comment: Sorry, missed that. The `=>` was slightly off my screen. Ignore me.

Answer (score 0):

Basically with thin functions or low levels of nesting functions (Scope Chaining) there is no difference. But in order to avoid low performance as the app grows it is recommended to use `context`. If you can, please read Chapter 2 of *High performance Javascript, N.Zakas* where there is a fully explained case with performance graphs attached.